# AR.Drone development for Android

Tags: android, c++, iphone, ar.drone

I knows that the AR.Drone is controllable for Android phone.

However I can't found any open java source code for me to develop!!

All I have found is the code with the type .h which I knows only for
C++ (iPhone user)!

Can any body give me some idea to develop AR.Drone with java code on eclipse?

thx
:)

Answer (score 1):

there is javadrone ( http://code.google.com/p/javadrone/ ) 
Note: this lib has issues with the AR.Drone 2.0  - fixed ( for at least flying ) here: https://github.com/xperimental/moder.AR.drone/blob/master/library_projects/javadrone-api/src/com/codeminders/ardrone/ARDrone.java

Comment: then you could think about voting this answer up or even accepting it ;-)
here is another example for you which uses this lib https://github.com/ligi/SpaceAR.Drone

Answer (score 0):

The AR Drone application programing interface API can be found here:

https://projects.ardrone.org/

The API is in c++, if you intend to develop for iphone you will have to write an application from the ground up because the application that exists on the iphon currently is commercial. (Closed source).

As is the android one because they are developed by parrot.

I developed for the ar drone using the computer which was much easier, depending on what you are trying to do i would develop on the computer. If you need more help i would suggest asking here:

http://www.ardrone-flyers.com/

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

We used [yaDrone](http://vsis-www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/oldServer/teaching//projects/yadrone/) for an [autonomous drone project](http://henning-gross.de/tubesync.php?v=W3siaWQiOiJkNGgyUWpkUmVYdyIsInN0YXJ0IjowfSx7ImlkIjoieVpNRTNUbXBLUzgiLCJzdGFydCI6MH1d#play) - the library was very reliable.

Furthermore there is an [eclipse tutorial for yaDrone](http://vsis-www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/oldServer/teaching//projects/yadrone/tutorial/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to build an IOS app you can use openFramework and ofxARDRone from Memo Akten to control and get the video. This framework is written in C++. You can use this framework in XCode and build for IOS, too.